# Need help typing mongoose models

Tags: typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose, schema

i'm working with products and categories

##### i've created these two types

```js
type Category = {
    parent: Category | null;  // is this ok?
    name: String;
};
type Product = {
    categories: Category[];
    name: String;
    qty: Number;
    price: Number;
};
```

##### then i've created the models

```js
// category model
import { Schema, Types, model } from "mongoose";
import Category from "../types/Category";

const categorySchema = new Schema(
    {
        parent: { type: Types.Array<Category>, required: true },
        name: { type: String, required: true },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

export default model("Product", categorySchema);
```

```js
// product model
import { Schema, Types, model } from "mongoose";
import Category from "../types/Category";

const productSchema = new Schema(
    {
        categories: { type: Types.Array<Category>, required: true },
        name: String,
        qty: Number,
        price: Number,
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

export default model("Product", productSchema);
```

##### vs code shows no error but when i run the server that's the error i get:

TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `MongooseArray` is not a valid type at path `categories`.

isn't productSchema's categories type an array of Category?

i've also tried `categories: { type: [Category], required: true }` with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are may ways to do this but to be simple just use this

```
const productSchema = new Schema(
    {
        categories: { type: [], required: true },
        name: String,
        qty: Number,
        price: Number,
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

//this also works for me whenever I want to store an array or object
//or just leaving category without a type

const productSchema = new Schema(
    {
        categories: { [] , required: true },
        name: String,
        qty: Number,
        price: Number,
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);
```

Comment: The second part is invalid syntax

Comment: ok sorry i wantend to say  ,  categories : [ ]